# Scala/ Spark- Multiply an Integer with each value in a Dataframe Column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a sample dataframe

```
df_that_I_have
+---------+---------+-------+
| country | members | some  |
+---------+---------+-------+
| India   | 50      | 1     |
+---------+---------+-------+
| Japan   | 20      | 3     |
+---------+---------+-------+
| India   | 20      | 1     |
+---------+---------+-------+
| Japan   | 10      | 3     |
+---------+---------+-------+
```

and I want a dataframe that looks like this

```
df_that_I_want
+---------+---------+-------+
| country | members | some  |
+---------+---------+-------+
| India   | 70      | 10    | // 5 * Sum of "some" for India, i.e. (1 + 1)
+---------+---------+-------+
| Japan   | 30      | 30    | // 5 * Sum of "some" for Japan, i.e. (3 + 3)
+---------+---------+-------+
```

The second dataframe has the sum of `members` and the sum of `some` multiplied 5.

This is what I'm doing to achieve this

```
val df_that_I_want = df_that_I_have
                        .select(df_that_I_have("country"),
                                df_that_I_have.groupBy("country").sum("members"),
                                5 * df_that_I_have.groupBy("country").sum("some")) //Problem here
```

But the compiler does not allow me to do this because apparently I can't multiply 5 with a column.

How can I multiply an Integer value with the sum of `some` for each country?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try [lit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#lit(java.lang.Object)) function.

```
scala> val df_that_I_have = Seq(("India",50,1),("India",20,1),("Japan",20,3),("Japan",10,3)).toDF("Country","Members","Some")
df_that_I_have: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Country: string, Members: int, Some: int]

scala> val df1 = df_that_I_have.groupBy("country").agg(sum("members"), sum("some") * lit(5))
df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [country: string, sum(members): bigint, ((sum(some),mode=Complete,isDistinct=false) * 5): bigint]

scala> val df_that_I_want= df1.select($"Country",$"sum(Members)".alias("Members"), $"((sum(Some),mode=Complete,isDistinct=false) * 5)".alias("Some"))
df_that_I_want: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Country: string, Members: bigint, Some: bigint]

scala> df_that_I_want.show

+-------+-------+----+
|Country|Members|Some|
+-------+-------+----+
|  India|     70|  10|
|  Japan|     30|  30|
+-------+-------+----+
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this

```
df_that_I_have.select("country").groupBy("country").agg(sum("members"), sum("some") * lit(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

`df_that_I_have.select("country").groupBy("country").agg(sum("members"), sum("some") * lit(5))`

lit function is used for creating the column of literal value which is 5 here.

when you are not able to multiply 5 directly, it is creating a column containing 5 and multiplying with it.